# Android odata4j Consumer EntitySet not found

Tags: android, odata, edmx, odata4j

I am trying to put some data from Android to an OData Server:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
    <Schema Namespace="DBModel">
      <EntityType Name="insertData">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
        </Key>
        <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
        <Property Name="double_data" Type="Edm.Double"/>
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Data">
      <EntityContainer Name="DataEntities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
        <EntitySet Name="insertStuff" EntityType="DBModel.insertData"/>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

My method to send the data to the server:

```
public class DataTransmitter {
  String serviceUrl = "http://url.tld/Data.svc";
  String entitySet = "insertStuff";

  ODataJerseyConsumer c = ODataJerseyConsumer.newBuilder(serviceUrl).build();

  void sendData(double data, UUID uuid) throws Exception {
    OEntity newLocation = c.createEntity(entitySet)
        .properties(OProperties.guid("ID", uuid.toString()))
        .properties(OProperties.double_("double_data", data))
        .execute();
}
```

Whenever I start the Application I get the following error on `adb logcat`:

```
org.odata4j.exceptions.NotFoundException: EdmEntitySet insertStuff is not found
```

I guess I have to include the Namespace `DBModel` somehow. But I don't know how, and can't seem to find it in the documentation.

**EDIT:** I included the line `ODataConsumer.dump.all(true);` to see what the Client is receiving from the server. I can see the whole `$metadata` as shown above in the output.

```
I/System.out( 2984): GET http://url.tld/Data.svc/$metadata
I/System.out( 2984): Accept: application/xml
I/System.out( 2984): User-Agent: odata4j.org
I/System.out( 2984): Status: 200
I/System.out( 2984): Cache-Control: no-cache
I/System.out( 2984): Content-Length: 1455
I/System.out( 2984): Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8
I/System.out( 2984): DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
I/System.out( 2984): Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 17:39:34 GMT
I/System.out( 2984): Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
I/System.out( 2984): X-Android-Received-Millis: 1354642777769
I/System.out( 2984): X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1354642777536
I/System.out( 2984): X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
I/System.out( 2984): X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I/System.out( 2984): X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
I/System.out( 2984): <edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
I/System.out( 2984):   <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
I/System.out( 2984):     <Schema Namespace="DBModel" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
I/System.out( 2984):       <EntityType Name="insertData">
I/System.out( 2984):         <Key>
I/System.out( 2984):           <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
I/System.out( 2984):         </Key>
I/System.out( 2984):         <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
I/System.out( 2984):         <Property Name="double_data" Type="Edm.Double" />
I/System.out( 2984):       </EntityType>
I/System.out( 2984):     </Schema>
I/System.out( 2984):     <Schema Namespace="Data" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
I/System.out( 2984):       <EntityContainer Name="DataEntities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
I/System.out( 2984):         <EntitySet Name="insertStuff" EntityType="DBModel.insertData" />
I/System.out( 2984):       </EntityContainer>
I/System.out( 2984):     </Schema>
I/System.out( 2984):   </edmx:DataServices>
I/System.out( 2984): </edmx:Edmx>
```

So the client is able to connect to the server *AND* accessing the EntitySet `insertStuff`. But still it shows the error

```
E/MainActivity(  987): null
E/MainActivity(  987): org.odata4j.exceptions.NotFoundException: EdmEntitySet insertStuff is not found
E/MainActivity(  987):  at org.odata4j.edm.EdmDataServices.getEdmEntitySet(EdmDataServices.java:55)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at org.odata4j.internal.EdmDataServicesDecorator.getEdmEntitySet(EdmDataServicesDecorator.java:36)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at org.odata4j.consumer.ConsumerCreateEntityRequest.execute(ConsumerCreateEntityRequest.java:42)
.
.
.
E/MainActivity(  987):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4966)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
E/MainActivity(  987):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that this is related to the bug postet here: [Issue 226: odata4j doesn't recognize WCF-$metadata correctly](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/issues/detail?id=226&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)

So to fix that all I had to do is to create the odata4j-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT-clientbundle.jar based on the current odata4j sources. Because a fix is already included in the 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT ([Issue 226 fix](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/detail?r=09bfd54271ab))

Sorry about asking here before consulting the bug reports!

Comment: Too bad, odata4j has been abandoned. I tried to solve the issue for 4 hours. Is there a better OData client for WCF other than odata4j?